# Do I need to upgrade Android SDK from 11 to 12 to implement latest release requirement

Tags: android, sdk

I have written an Android app back in 2021. And I need to do a software upgrade on my app. I used SDK 11 and SDKtarget = 30 in gradle. So app store requires SDKtarget = 31 for latest releases. So I need to know if I need to upgrade my SDK in build tools to 12 as well? I am using bluetooth scan and connect in app as well. So I need to implement the runtime permission also in my code.

Comment: Yes, we have to modify it. and run time permission is mandatory.

Comment: You are as a developer define your target users and their devices. Google play might add extra requirement, but it is not a single channel of distribution, although it is important one. Based on your current constraints and requirements, your target sdk should be rised up to 31. The best practice is to support the latest Android release too.